# uitableview increase space between tableview and sectionindex

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to increase the spacing between the tableview and the section-index like in this picture:

[image]

How can I achieve this without any dirty hacks because the rows are selectable and getting a checkmark if selected, so any empty view hacks will not work correctly because the checkmarks.

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: How it looks like now?

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize your design a bit by adding an extra Container UIView into the cell which will add virtual gap from the right of the cell, and keep the cell transparent. See below in the image

**Storyboard Design**
[image]

**Outcome**

[image]

Hope it helps.

Cheers.